# Set Text to be Underline without Selection

Tags: ios, ios6, nsattributedstring, underline

I am trying to allow users the ability to set text they will type as underline, without having text currently selected. This is for an iOS 6 app, entering text in a UITextView. It will be saved as an NSAttributedString. Bold and italic work fine. Something about underline is keeping it from working.

```
UITextView *textView = [self noteTextView];
NSMutableDictionary *typingAttributes = [[textView typingAttributes] mutableCopy];
[typingAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
NSLog(@"attributes after: %@", typingAttributes);
[textView setTypingAttributes:typingAttributes];
NSLog(@"text view attributes after: %@", [textView typingAttributes]);
```

My initial log statement indicates it is set to underline:

```
attributes after: {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0xa9c5e30> font-family: \"Verdana\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```

But the log statement immediately after doesn't show an nsunderline attribute. Removing the textView setTypingAttributes line has no affect.

```
text view attributes after: {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0xa9c5e30> font-family: \"Verdana\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

I'm stumped why I have it working for bold and italic, but not underline. Also why it seems to initially get the attribute, then forget it. Please share any insight you may have. Thanks.

Comment: Try using the System Font. Not sure if the underline is drawn or its a glyph in the font.

Comment: Have the exact same problem, it retains all attributes I've tried except underline (I tried font, background color, fore-color, text alignment, etc they all work fine). Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've found a bug, or at least some undocumented behavior. If I set the typing attributes to red, I can do it:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
        replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDictionary* d = textField.typingAttributes;
    NSLog(@"%@", d);
    NSMutableDictionary* md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:d];
    // md[NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] = @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle);
    md[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [UIColor redColor];
    textField.typingAttributes = md;
    return YES;
}
```

With that code, all the user's new typing comes out red. But if I uncomment the commented line, trying to add underlining to the typing attributes, it breaks the whole thing - I don't get underlining, and I don't get red coloring either!

The answer to the other part of your question, though, *is* documented. You have to do it the way I'm doing it, reasserting the typing attributes as the user types, because, as the documentation clearly states, "When the text field’s selection changes, the contents of the dictionary are cleared automatically" (that's the "forgetting" you asked about).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I thought it was just me! Having read your post, I've done quite a bit of testing. As you mention, Underline doesn't work as a preformatting option using typingAttributes. Neither does strikethrough. Everything else I've tried (foreground & background colors) seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, DenVog - I filed a bug on this, and I suggest you do so too.

Comment: I filed a bug as well. Though given that I have some still open from June, I won't hold my breath of getting a fix any time soon.

Comment: Many of my bugs have been open for years. The important thing is numbers of reports. Apple has explicitly said that they pay more attention to bugs that have been reported more times.

Comment: I had the same issue, tried reporting the bug, but there is a bug in the bug-reporting page and gives me this error "An error has occurred". How can I report this bug related to their bug-reporter? :)

Comment: In my testing, in iOS 7.1 you can use strikethrough with `typingAttributes`, but you need to set `typingAttributes` after you set any attributed text.

Comment: @phatmann Yes, what you've found here is a discussion of an iOS 6 bug. It was fixed in iOS 7.

Comment: @matt, the point I was trying to make was that `typingAttributes` needs to be set after `attributedText` for "preformatting" to work, even in iOS 7. I did not see that mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: @phatmann See the docs on `typingAttributes`: it's pretty clear there. Changing the `attributedText` changes the selection. But changing the selection clears the `typingAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 6, UITextView now declares property attributedText which allows you to underline text by creating an NSAttributedString.  Here is the modified code:

```
UITextView *textView = [self noteTextView];
NSMutableDictionary *typingAttributes = [[textView typingAttributes] mutableCopy];
[typingAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
NSLog(@"attributes after: %@", typingAttributes);
textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[textView text] attributes:typingAttributes];
NSLog(@"text view attributes after: %@", [textView typingAttributes]);
```

By using this code, any further text that is typed will also conform to the format set out in your NSAttributedString e.g. underlining

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are correct about the use of typingAttributes for selection length of zero. But I do not find this works for underline or strikethrough.